# ASP.net DataView - Cant apply filter

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

I'm building a website in asp.net with C#.

I'm trying to put use a dataview so I can Filter a Dataset which I then return to a gridView.

The problem is that it ignores the filter and just shows the entire dataset.

Here is my code ( left some parts out to be less confusing )

```
public class CData
{
 private SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString);
 private DataSet ds= new DataSet();
 private SqlDataAdapter da;
 private DataView dv;
 private SqlCommandBuilder cb;

public CData()
{
 string sql = String.Format("SELECT * FROM table");
 da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cn);
 da.Fill(ds, "Table");
 dv= new DataView(ds.Tables["Table"]);
 cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
}

public DataTable FilterByFk(Int32 FK)
 {
   dv.RowFilter = "FK = "+ FK;
   dv.RowStateFilter = DataViewRowState.ModifiedCurrent;
   da.Update(ds, "Table");
   return ds.Tables["Table"];
 }
}
```

anyone know what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where you are calling your method to filter.  Also, to apply the RowFilter correctly you need to specify the name of a column followed by an operator and a value to filter on.  With the value wrapped in single quotes.  Try the following:

```
dv.RowFilter = String.Format("FK = '{0}'", FK);
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'I don't see where you are calling your method to filter.'? I'm trying to filter the dataset 'ds'. thanks for the reply!

Comment: I don't see a call made to method FilterByFk but that may be something you left out on purpose but the quotes '' are definitely needed regardless of the datatype for the value.

Comment: Ah yes I call that method using a objectdatasource in my aspx page. then I link it to a gridview.

Comment: You should return the dataview instead of the datatable in FilterByFk.

Comment: I tried that but it alwayse returns empty, even if remove the filter.

should I put somthing after dv to return the data ? currently I have
 
public DataView FilterByFk(Int32 FK)
...
return dv;

Comment: Ah its seems like I needed to allow sorting and callback on the gridview, got it fixed now!